# Coroutine does not resume after WaitForSeconds

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines

None of the code after wait for seconds runs in the example below.

The idea is to stop the player attacking for 1 second after he hits an enemy.

When I run this code, `Debug.Log` "start coroutine" appears in the console, but "endcoroutine" doesn't, and CanHit doesn't return to true.

How can I fix this so the coroutine resumes after the wait?

```
public class Attack : MonoBehaviour

{

private bool CanHit = true;

   private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        IDamageable Hit = other.GetComponent<IDamageable>();

        if (Hit != null && CanHit == true)
        {
            Hit.Damage();
            StartCoroutine(ResetDamage());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ResetDamage()
    {
        CanHit = false;
        Debug.Log("start coroutine");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        Debug.Log("end coroutine");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you don't have `CanHit = true;` anywhere in the code you have provided.

Comment: Does something destroy or deactivate the game object this coroutine is running on in the second while it's waiting? Coroutine lifetime is tied to the instance that started it, so this can kill the coroutine before it has a chance to resume.

Comment: Ye I deactivated the instance in the last few frames of the animation!!! All sorted now thanx @DMGregory

Answer (score 0):

nothing to do with the code0. I had disabled the object the code was attached to in the last few frames of my animation, that's what was causing the issue.